# The longest consecutive days streak

Tags: support, consecutive-days

How can I check the **longest** (not current) personal consecutive days streak?

I remember there was such a possibility, but I can't find it now.

Comment: As below (in case of post deletion): Nah, I know this counter exists but I'm looking for the longest streak. I remember somewhere on the site, I accidentally came across an information about my last lost many days after I'd lost it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your request at first. The necessary information can be retrieved from a URL like this: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/daily-site-access/295232` where the last number is your user ID (found in the URL of your profile). That page looks empty, but if you check the source, you'll see that it defines a variable 'visited' which contains all dates you visited the site (the first level keys are 'year', next 'month', finally 'day'):

[image]

You could use that to write a script iterating over the object to tell you what your longest streak is and when it was. @ShadowWizard did it in [the other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362512/295232); for other solutions, check upcoming answers to [my first Code Golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/222876/38979).

Comment: how did you even find that!?

Comment: @mindstormsboi Firefox developer tools (but other browsers have it too), Network tab

Comment: @Glorfindel New inforamtion to me, Is there any help or faq about the "/daily-site-access" URL?

Comment: @Arulkumar it's likely just an internal API, there's no information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22daily-site-access%22

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh, got it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Not a golfer, but that was a fair exercise for my rusty plain JS skills. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Following the advice in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362501/152859), I've written a script that parse the results and showing the top one, i.e. the longest consecutive day streak. Just copy and paste the below script into the browser's console and run it, while in any page on SE site.

```js
var showAll = false; //change to true in order to log the full list to console
function consecutiveData() {
    this.add = function(date) {
        this.consecutiveDaysCount++;
        if (this.firstDay == null) {
            this.firstDay = new Date(date);
        }
        this.lastDay = new Date(date);
    };
    this.toString = function() {
        return this.consecutiveDaysCount + " consecutive days between " + this.firstDay + " and " + this.lastDay;
    };
    this.consecutiveDaysCount = 0;
    this.firstDay = null;
    this.lastDay = null;
}
var userId = $(".my-profile").attr("href").split("/")[2];
var url = "/users/daily-site-access/" + userId;
console.log("Fetching daily site access for user " + userId + "...");
$.get(url, function(resp) {
    var lookFor = "var visited = ";
    var index1 = resp.indexOf(lookFor);
    var index2 = resp.indexOf("\n", index1);
    if (index1 < 0 || index2 < 0) {
        console.log("Failed to get proper data please visit " + url + " and check what went wrong.");
        return;
    }
    var rawJSON = resp.substr(index1 + lookFor.length, index2 - (index1 + lookFor.length + 1));
    var tmp = rawJSON.split(":");
    tmp.forEach((t, i) => {
        if (t.indexOf(",") >= 0 || t.indexOf("{") >= 0) {
            tmp[i] = t.replace(',', ',"').replace('{', '{"') + '"';
        }
    });
    var jsonWithQuotes = tmp.join(":").replace(";", "");
    var visited = JSON.parse(jsonWithQuotes);
    var firstYear = Object.keys(visited)[0];
    var firstMonth = Object.keys(visited[firstYear])[0];
    var firstDay = Object.keys(visited[firstYear][firstMonth])[0];
    var date = new Date(firstYear, firstMonth - 1, firstDay);
    console.log("Success! Checking activity since " + date);
    var now = new Date();
    var consecutiveDaysList = [];
    var consecutiveDaysBuffer = null;
    while (date < now) {
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var day = date.getDate();
        if (visited[year] && visited[year][month + 1] && visited[year][month + 1][day]) {
            if (consecutiveDaysBuffer == null)
                consecutiveDaysBuffer = new consecutiveData();
            consecutiveDaysBuffer.add(date);
        } else {
            if (consecutiveDaysBuffer != null)
                consecutiveDaysList.push(consecutiveDaysBuffer);
            consecutiveDaysBuffer = null;
        }
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    if (consecutiveDaysBuffer != null)
        consecutiveDaysList.push(consecutiveDaysBuffer);
    consecutiveDaysList.sort((cd1, cd2) => cd2.consecutiveDaysCount - cd1.consecutiveDaysCount);
    var topResult = consecutiveDaysList[0];
    console.log("Top result: " + topResult.toString());
    if (showAll) {
        console.log("Full list of consecutive days:");
        console.log(consecutiveDaysList);
    }
});
```

Comment: JavaScript? What context does it run in? [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q no the context is the current page you're viewing in the browser, assuming you're using the browser's developer console. This can be made into userscript, I'm just not there yet.

Comment: I just used it and the result was... as expected: Top result: 4321 consecutive days between Thu May 28 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) and Fri Mar 26 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

Comment: @VonC that's... very impressive. Well done! :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. :/ Outputs "43 days", while the user profile says "1450 days".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat weird. Can you please change the first line to `var showAll = true;` and check where the glitch is? You can also copy and paste [here](https://pastebin.com/) the results and I'll have a look.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Here's the log: https://pastebin.com/ahJLcz9G

Comment: @HolyBlackCat interesting, I'll take a closer look when having some time to debug. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, think I figured it. The 1450 days you see is the total amount of days you visited, **not** consecutive. The consecutive count is shown later, e.g. for me it says "Visited 3597 days, 45 consecutive". You don't see any consecutive count because you don't have it yet, it doesn't show one day as being consecutive, so it's just saying the total amount of days.

Comment:  I didn't realize the count is per site, not global. 1450 days are on SO, not MSE. Tried to run the same script from a SO tab, go this: https://pastebin.com/C5uqB63T

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ohh... lol. So all good now?

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Only that it errors out when ran on SO. Is it supposed to work on MSE only, or any SE site I have open when running it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh wait... think you found a bug, when you didn't visit for whole month it will crash. Reproduced on small site I don't visit often, I'll fix and edit the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat bug fixed, try now. :)

Comment: Yup, it works now! Thanks. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank *you*, for being a loyal beta tester... ;)